# HTML/JS/CSS3 + ASPX ... And Sharepoint Designer 2013

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

i'm becoming mad... I would like to add this bar:

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [bindtuning.com](http://academy.bindtuning.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/SP2013SuiteBar.png))</sub>

(using seattle.master - view)

in a simple custom page created by me.
In my case, I've "index.aspx" in the same folder of "Home.aspx" (the folder is SitePages),

"index.aspx" is a Html5 page w/ css3 and js pages (I uploaded the code just to have a complete post)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register tagprefix="SharePoint" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*" %>

<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HomePage | Fabio Test's Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="default" runat="server"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/css/main_style.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/css/fractionslider.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/css/navigation.css' type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/css/slider.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
<script src='../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/js/jquery.color-RGBa-patch.js'></script>
<script src="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src='../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/js/navigation.js'></script> 
<script src="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/js/jquery.fractionslider.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/js/main.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/js/mosaic.1.0.1.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">  

            jQuery(function($){

                $('.bar2').mosaic({
                    animation   :   'slide'     //fade or slide
                });

            });


        </script>
                <!--[if gte IE 9]>
                  <style type="text/css">
                    .gradient {
                       filter: none;
                    }
                  </style>
                <![endif]-->

</head>

<body oncontextmenu="return false" onselectstart="return false">
   <div id="site_content">
   <noscript>Javascript?</noscript>

   <div id="top_bar"><br/><br/>
     <img id="logo" alt="Logo" src="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/img/logo.jpg" />
      </div>



        <div id="centralign">
            <div class="centralDiv_first mosaic-block bar2" id="first_div">
                <a href="#" class="mosaic-overlay">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h4>MIS</h4><br/>
                        <p>Management of Information Systems</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/img/centralDiv/icon_1.jpg" onclick="window.open('#','_self',false)"/></div>
            </div>
            <div class="centralDiv_first mosaic-block bar2" id="second_div">
                <a href="#" class="mosaic-overlay">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h4>Finance</h4><br/>
                        <p>I hope that there are money for sponsorships.</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/img/centralDiv/icon_2.jpg" onclick="window.open('#','_self',false)"/></div>
            </div>
            <div class="centralDiv_first mosaic-block bar2" id="third_div">
                <a href="#" class="mosaic-overlay">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h4>HR</h4><br/>
                        <p>Human Resources</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/img/centralDiv/icon_3.jpg" onclick="window.open('#','_self',false)"/></div>
            </div>
            <div class="centralDiv_first mosaic-block bar2" id="fourth_div">
                <a href="#" class="mosaic-overlay">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h4>Forms</h4><br/>
                        <p>Check it out!</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/img/centralDiv/icon_4.jpg" onclick="window.open('https://uscri.sharepoint.com/Forms/Forms/AllItems.aspx','_self',false)"/></div>
            </div>


                <a href="#">
                    <div class="centralDiv_second mosaic-block bar">
                        <div class="mosaic-backdrop">
                            <img src="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/img/centralDiv/icon_small_1.jpg"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="centralDiv_second mosaic-block bar">
                        <div class="mosaic-backdrop">
                            <img src="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/img/centralDiv/icon_small_2.jpg"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="centralDiv_second mosaic-block bar">
                        <div class="mosaic-backdrop">
                            <img src="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/img/centralDiv/icon_small_3.jpg"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="centralDiv_second mosaic-block bar">
                        <div class="mosaic-backdrop">
                            <img src="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/img/centralDiv/icon_small_4.jpg"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="centralDiv_second mosaic-block bar">
                        <div class="mosaic-backdrop">
                            <img src="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/img/centralDiv/icon_small_5.jpg"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <a href="#">
                    <div class="centralDiv_second mosaic-block bar">
                        <div class="mosaic-backdrop">
                            <img src="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/img/centralDiv/icon_small_undefined.jpg"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>            
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="centralDiv_second mosaic-block bar">
                        <div class="mosaic-backdrop">
                            <img src="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/img/centralDiv/icon_small_undefined.jpg"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>    
            <a href="#">
                    <div class="centralDiv_second mosaic-block bar">
                        <div class="mosaic-backdrop">
                            <img src="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/img/centralDiv/icon_small_undefined.jpg"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>    
        </div><br/><br/>
        <div id="footer">For general inquiries, please email</div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to modify the seattle.master, trying to leave just the top bar (called SuiteBar) and wrote the code in the had tag and in the body, but javascript doesn't work and also there is an overwriting of tags in css files.

I appreciate any suggestion to solve the problem!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

most probalbly the JS and the css are not referenced correctly.

the code above is a master page. try to use the following 
/SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/css/main_style.css just remove the ../

assuming you have a document library called SiteAssets in the rooSite as / is always referring to the rootsite, and you have a folder called SitePages inside this document library and another one under Sitepages called Home ... etc.

if your SiteAssets document library is not in the rootsite and you want to reference it in the current subsite use the directive <%$ SPUrl: ~site/SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/css/main_style.css %>